# How to create an array of objects with available time slots

Tags: javascript

On my frontend application I'm fetching available appointements slots of an user.

Actually, my API is giving available dates like that :

> ["2021-02-20T10:00:00.000Z",
> "2021-02-20T11:00:00.000Z",
> "2021-02-21T08:00:00.000Z",
> "2021-02-21T09:00:00.000Z"]

As you can see, there are 2 different days with 2 different time each ones.

What I would like to have is this:

```
[
    {
        date: '2021-02-20T10:00:00.000Z',
        slots: [
            {
                date: '2021-02-20T10:00:00.000Z'
            },
            {
                date: '2021-02-20T11:00:00.000Z'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        date: '2021-02-21T08:00:00.000Z',
        slots: [
            {
                date: '2021-02-21T08:00:00.000Z'
            },
            {
                date: '2021-02-21T09:00:00.000Z'
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Because I would like to show 2 different dates and inside, their corresponding times.
Do you have any idea? I'm using Quasar framework so I can use Date() from Quasar or even Momentjs.

Thanks

---

EDIT for @charlietfl

```
@Get('/appointment/professionals/:id')
  async getAvailabilityProfessionals(@Req() req: Request, @Param('id') id: string, @Query() params: any) {
    const { from, to } = params
    const professional = await this.professionalsService.findProfessionalById(id)
    const thisDay = new Date(from)
    const lastDay = new Date(to)
    const data = professional.availability.filter(date => date >= thisDay && date <= lastDay)

    const grouped = data.reduce((a, c) => {
      const day = c.toString().slice(0, 10)
      a[day] = a[day] || { date: c, slots: [] }
      a[day].slots.push({ date: c })
      return a
    }, {})
    return Object.values(grouped)
  }
```

Comment: simply said, this is a mapping exercise, someone would probably bring a regex example of making strings in that format with less lines of code(as in just the return part with data being some regex version of each string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a "groupBy" operation where you use the common values (unique dates) as object keys and update that object or create a new one as needed.

Then once the grouping is done you get the values of the grouped object

```js
const grouped = data.reduce((a,c)=>{
    const day = c.slice(0,10)
    a[day] = a[day] || {date: c, slots: []}
    a[day].slots.push({date: c})
    return a
},{})

const res = Object.values(grouped)

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
const data = ["2021-02-20T10:00:00.000Z", "2021-02-20T11:00:00.000Z", "2021-02-21T08:00:00.000Z", "2021-02-21T09:00:00.000Z"]
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like expected! 
I'm wondering how can I edit that because I need the same thing but: 

I need that API returns evey days even if they got no slots.
Actually the GET call giving in params two dates (from and to) and the API returns every available dates like my initial post. But what I finally need, is the API returns each days even if they don't have slot. thanks

Comment: I edited the main topic to show my actual working code, if you have any time to check that out

Answer (score 1):

This seemed a straightforward format, so I used a combination of splits to be able to make new strings in the format you wanted :D

```js
let apiData=["2021-02-20T10:00:00.000Z", "2021-02-20T11:00:00.000Z", "2021-02-21T08:00:00.000Z", "2021-02-21T09:00:00.000Z"]

function conversion(arr){
  return arr.map(a=>{
    var toSplitBy=a.split('T')[1].split(':')[0] //returns number between T and :
    var splitText=a.split(toSplitBy) //split for each date part in the slots array to have its correct value when combining again
    return({ //mapped object for each index of arr to return
      date:a,
      slots:[
        {date:splitText[0]+(toSplitBy)+splitText[1]},
        {date:splitText[0]+(toSplitBy*1+1)+splitText[1]}
      ]
    })
  })
}
var convertedData=conversion(apiData)
console.log(convertedData)
```